# capturing object id from a url in django view not in urls.py?

Tags: django, url

I know django.conf.urls.defaults.url extracts regular expression to get object-id or others.

I wonder if I can do the same thing in my view.

Suppose I have a url rule such as `url(r'^/path1/path2/(?P<my_object_id>\d+)/path3, my_view, name='my_view_name')`
In a view, I have a string that matches the url such as `/path1/path2/34/path3`, how can I get the `34` from the string?

ie, Is there a function which takes view_name(or the same url regex in urls.py), and a url string and returns positional/keyword arguments as the `url()` does it?

```
foo(view_name, url_string): 
  ... 
  return (args, kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`django.core.urlresolvers.resolve`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reference 34 using my_object_id.

Here's the relevant text from the [django tutorial polls app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial03/):

> The poll_id='34' part comes from (?P\d+). Using parentheses around a pattern
>   “captures” the text matched by that pattern and sends it as an argument to the view
>   function; ?P defines the name that will be used to identify the matched pattern;
>   and \d+ is a regular expression to match a sequence of digits (i.e., a number).